# Stuck on how to scrape a web-page containing a JavaScript form

Tags: python

Background: I'm currently stuck trying to scrape a web-page (using Python3) that contains a JavaScript form. My main goal is to scrape the form, get the input fields, and then post data to the fields so I can automatically create accounts.

Does anyone know how to do this without using Selenium (trying to stay away from Selenium as I heard it was volatile)?

Comment: "trying to stay away from Selenium as I heard it was volatile" I have found that it's better to test out these things for yourself. AFAIK there is no good way to scrape JS related info without a browser of some sort. I use selenium a decent bit and have had good results. It is a little slower than just using requests obviously, but thats the price of scraping JS, until a better solution is identified

Comment: You might not need to scrape the form itself. You just need to know what URL it posts to, whether it uses GET or POST, and what the names of the fields are. You can find all that out by hand using your browser's developer tools.